# What do call criminals who don't go to jail

Tags: word-request

In countries that are banana republics, some bad actors commit crimes and get away with it. It's common knowledge; to the media,cops; that they are criminals  and no legal action is taken against them.

What would would describe these actors.

Felon and convicts are people who are or have been to jail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a "convict" is a person who has been convicted,  a "criminal" is someone who has committed a crime.  Even if they have little fear of being arrested (because of the failure of the justice system) they can still be called a "criminal", at least in a normal context.

There are plenty of other words, some more specific, some more general: wrongdoer, crook, swindler, racketeer, mafioso/a, yakuza, or your term "bad actor".

But simply "criminal" is the most fitting term for "bad actors [who] commit crimes".

Answer (score 1):

You could say a "fugitive" or simply "criminal". Although its more for a criminal who escaped jail. But it is technically a criminal who isn't in jail.

Comment: I am talking about people who openly commit crime and get away with it, because they have some sort of political influence. Like some low level mafia.

Comment: "Criminals powerful enough to escape justice" or similar. I don't think there is any single word for such a person.

Comment: The word "impunity" describes freedom from negative consequences associated with one's actions. It is common to say they act "with impunity", or that they are "unpunished". To describe that they are receiving protection from the justice system, one could say they are being "shielded" from prosecution.